# Segmentation fault on inserting axidma module on petalinux 2018.1

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, dma

I followed this rep [xilinx-axidma by brandon](https://github.com/bperez77/xilinx_axidma) and [Used the driver with petalinux](https://github.com/bperez77/xilinx_axidma/issues/24), but,
I got a segmentation fault when I try to `insmod xilinx-axidma.ko` at /lib/modules/4.14.0-xilinx-v2018.1/extra/xilinx-axidma.ko

Note : My dma design only has rx channel

Here are the logs :

```
[ 702.381163] xilinx_axidma: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 702.388131] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at  virtual address 00000000
[ 702.396157] Mem abort info:
[ 702.398910] Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[ 702.404818] SET = 0, FnV = 0
[ 702.407853] EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[ 702.410973] Data abort info:
[ 702.413843] ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000006
[ 702.417662] CM = 0, WnR = 0
[ 702.420616] user pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgd = ffffffc07b3ee000
[ 702.427125] [0000000000000000] *pgd=000000007b3ab003, *pud=000000007b3ab003, *pmd=0000000000000000
[ 702.436077] Internal error: Oops: 96000006 [#1] SMP
[ 702.440921] Modules linked in: xilinx_axidma(O+) uio_pdrv_genirq
[ 702.446914] CPU: 1 PID: 2273 Comm: insmod Tainted: G O
4.14.0-xilinx-v2018.1 #1
[ 702.455332] Hardware name: xlnx,zynqmp (DT)
[ 702.459496] task: ffffffc07a41c580 task.stack: ffffff800d280000
[ 702.465415] PC is at axidma_of_parse_dma_nodes+0x3e4/0x5b8
[xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.472269] LR is at axidma_of_parse_dma_nodes+0x254/0x5b8
[xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.479115] pc : [] lr : [] pstate: 60000145
[ 702.486493] sp : ffffff800d2839e0
[ 702.489788] x29: ffffff800d2839e0 x28: ffffff8000a5cc40
[ 702.495084] x27: ffffffc07fef4d88 x26: ffffffc07a5a2ea0
[ 702.500379] x25: ffffffc07a5a2e80 x24: 0000000000000001
[ 702.505674] x23: 0000000000000020 x22: ffffffc07b3d9200
[ 702.510969] x21: 0000000000000000 x20: 0000000000000001
[ 702.516264] x19: ffffffc07feef850 x18: 0000000000000001
[ 702.521558] x17: 00000000004a59b0 x16: ffffff800810b398
[ 702.526853] x15: ffffffffffffffff x14: 0000000000000000
[ 702.532148] x13: 0000000000000010 x12: 0101010101010101
[ 702.537443] x11: 0000000000000010 x10: 0101010101010101
[ 702.542738] x9 : 0000000000000002 x8 : 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
[ 702.548033] x7 : 6d2c606c62ff726b x6 : 0000000000000000
[ 702.553327] x5 : 0000000000000001 x4 : 0000000000000000
[ 702.558622] x3 : 0000000000000069 x2 : ffffff8000a5b4e0
[ 702.563917] x1 : ffffff8000a5c772 x0 : 0000000000000000
[ 702.569213] Process insmod (pid: 2273, stack limit = 0xffffff800d280000)
[ 702.575896] Call trace:
[ 702.578327] Exception stack(0xffffff800d2838a0 to 0xffffff800d2839e0)
[ 702.584753] 38a0: 0000000000000000 ffffff8000a5c772 ffffff8000a5b4e0 0000000000000069
[ 702.592566] 38c0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 6d2c606c62ff726b
[ 702.600378] 38e0: 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f 0000000000000002 0101010101010101 0000000000000010
[ 702.608190] 3900: 0101010101010101 0000000000000010 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff
[ 702.616002] 3920: ffffff800810b398 00000000004a59b0 0000000000000001 ffffffc07feef850
[ 702.623814] 3940: 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 ffffffc07b3d9200 0000000000000020
[ 702.631627] 3960: 0000000000000001 ffffffc07a5a2e80 ffffffc07a5a2ea0 ffffffc07fef4d88
[ 702.639439] 3980: ffffff8000a5cc40 ffffff800d2839e0 ffffff8000a5abec ffffff800d2839e0
[ 702.647251] 39a0: ffffff8000a5ad7c 0000000060000145 ffffff800d2839e0 ffffff8000a5abec
[ 702.655063] 39c0: 0000008000000000 0000000000000001 ffffff800d2839e0 ffffff8000a5ad7c
[ 702.662886] [] axidma_of_parse_dma_nodes+0x3e4/0x5b8 [xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.670784] [] axidma_dma_init+0xa4/0x280 [xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.677726] [] axidma_probe+0x40/0xf0 [xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.684318] [] platform_drv_probe+0x58/0xb8
[ 702.690043] [] driver_probe_device+0x22c/0x2d8
[ 702.696032] [] __driver_attach+0xbc/0xc0
[ 702.701499] [] bus_for_each_dev+0x4c/0x98
[ 702.707054] [] driver_attach+0x20/0x28
[ 702.712350] [] bus_add_driver+0x1b8/0x228
[ 702.717905] [] driver_register+0x60/0xf8
[ 702.723374] [] __platform_driver_register+0x40/0x48
[ 702.729807] [] axidma_init+0x18/0x1000 [xilinx_axidma]
[ 702.736482] [] do_one_initcall+0x38/0x128
[ 702.742037] [] do_init_module+0x58/0x1b0
[ 702.747504] [] load_module+0x19fc/0x2150
[ 702.752972] [] SyS_init_module+0xf8/0x178
[ 702.758526] Exception stack(0xffffff800d283ec0 to 0xffffff800d284000)
[ 702.764951] 3ec0: 000000001113a2e0 000000000000aee0 000000001113a260 000000001113a280
[ 702.772765] 3ee0: 0000000000000000 0000007f8d5d1580 0000007f8d6ac700 0000007f8d6ac700
[ 702.780577] 3f00: 0000000000000069 000000000000b001 0101010101010101 0000000000000000
[ 702.788389] 3f20: 0000000000000018 0000000000005b76 0000007f8d494d98 0000007f8d487d00
[ 702.796201] 3f40: 0000007f8d54ca80 00000000004a59b0 000000000000073f 0000007f8d6ac720
[ 702.804013] 3f60: 000000001113a2e0 000000001113a260 0000000000000002 0000007fd3ff33f8
[ 702.811825] 3f80: 0000000000000049 0000000000000000 00000000004a5000 0000000000000000
[ 702.819637] 3fa0: 0000000000000000 0000007fd3ff32c0 000000000040f368 0000007fd3ff31a0
[ 702.827449] 3fc0: 0000007f8d54caa4 0000000080000000 000000001113a2e0 0000000000000069
[ 702.835261] 3fe0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[ 702.843074] [] el0_svc_naked+0x24/0x28
[ 702.848367] Code: 58000ee2 2a1803e5 58000961 52800d23 (f94002a4)
[ 702.854442] ---[ end trace 5233cb4a2c13e94a ]---
Segmentation fault
```

My device tree:

```
    /dts-v1/;
    {
     dma@80004000 {
                            #dma-cells = <0x1>;
                            clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
                            clocks = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
                            compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
                            reg = <0x0 0x80004000 0x0 0x1000>;
                            xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
                            status = "okay";
                            linux,phandle = <0x33>;
                            phandle = <0x33>;
    
                            dma-channel@80004030 {
                                    compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
                                    dma-channels = <0x1>;
                                    xlnx,datawidth = <0x20>;
                                    xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
                            };
                    };
    
       axidma_chrdev@0 {
                    compatible = "xlnx,axidma-chrdev";
                    dmas = <0x33 0x1>;
                    dma-names = "rx_channel";
            };
    };
```

Comment: Something is `NULL` that's not supposed to be `NULL`. Possibly the driver expects a different DT node name than what you have, or maybe you are missing a node property. Using `addr2line` (or with good ol' printk-at-every-line) you could determine the exact line that causes the oops, and then check what's going on

Comment: how to use `addr2line` for debugging the driver.

Comment: `dma@80004000` only defines one DMA channel `dma-channel@80004030` so that will be channel 0. But `axidma_chrdev@0` `dmas` property is looking for non-existent channel 1. I think there is a missing `return -EINVAL;` (or possibly `return -ENOENT;` would be better) statement after `axidma_node_err(dma_chan_node, "Unable to find child node number %d.\n",` `channel);` in the definition of `axidma_of_parse_channel()` in "driver/axidma_of.c" causing it to call `of_find_property()` with a null pointer, but that should not cause a crash because it checks for null.

Comment: @IanAbbott if i define `axidma_chrdev@0`  `dmas` property as 0, i get somewhat of "Unable to find slave channel"  when `insmod`